# Why is my for loop returning multiple outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Why is this code returning multiple outputs
The code

```
a = ["w", "u", "i", "r"]


count = 0
d = input("choose: ")
for c in a:
    count += 1
    if d == c:
        print(count)
    else:
        print("wrong")
```

If I choose a string tha satisfies this condition "d==c", it returns the position of the string plus "wrong" three times,

If I choose a string doesn't satisfy the condition, it outputs wrong four times.

If I don't include the else part, it outputs only just the position of the string only once.

Please whats wrong with the code, as I need to include the else part

Comment: You need to put `break` statements after the `print`s so that the loop will stop.

Comment: What do you *want* the code to do?  Do you want to have it look at the whole string and then print either the complete counter or "wrong"?

Comment: You don't `return` anything (and you can't, as you aren't inside a function), you just `print` it.

Comment: @samwise yes, I want that, just print the index or wrong than the accompanied "wrong". and I don't want to use the index function, want to write my own index function

Comment: See my answer then -- the key thing is that you don't want the "wrong" condition to happen until the *end* of the loop, because it's not possible to know whether the input was wrong until after you've looked at *all* the letters.

Answer (score 1):

> If I choose a string that satisfies this condition "d==c", it returns the position of the string plus "wrong" three times,

Is this what you're trying to do?

```py
a = ["w", "u", "i", "r"]

d = input("choose: ")

for index, c in enumerate(a):
    if d == c:
        print(f"At index {index}")
    else:
        print("wrong")
```

Output :

```
>>> choose: i
wrong
wrong
At index 2
wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is find the index of an element in a list use the `.index` method:

```py
a = ["w", "u", "i", "r"]
print(a.index("u"))  -> 1
```

It returns an error if the element is not on list, you can overcome that by using a `try-except` or checking if the element is in the list:

```py
i = input("choose: ")
if i in a:
    print(a.index(i))
else:
    print("wrong")
```

or

```py
try:
    print(a.index(i))
except ValueError:
    print("wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is `break` when the match is found, and unindent the `else`:

```
a = "wuir"
count = 0
for c in a:
    count += 1
    if d == c:
        print(count)
        break
else:
    print("wrong")
```

Unindenting the `else` makes it part of the `for` statement, not the `if`.  This means that it will be executed only if the entire `for` loop finishes without a `break` -- which means you'll only get the `"wrong"` output at the very end of the loop if the `d == c` condition was never met.

Result:

```
choose: i
3
```

```
choose: f
wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is all good, but we need a small modification here, as you know when the value of **d==c** it will print the index, if we need to **stop** just right there so how about if we simply increment out **count** and if it's found then **stop the loop**,
Please try:

```
a = ["w", "u", "i", "r"]
count = 0
d = input("choose: ")
for c in a:
    if d == c:
        print(count)
        break
    count += 1
else:
   print("wrong")
```

> This will print the index if d is found in list a else it will print "wrong"